# Vertical jQuery Easy Accordion is needed

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-accordion

I have [jQuery Easy Accordion plugin](http://www.madeincima.eu/samples/jquery/easyAccordion/) in my site.It is originally horizontal accordion.But i need it in vertical style too. 
I need a vertical accordion with fix dimension that if the number of main title (main navigation items) changes it automatically calculate height of content area below each main items.

do you know how can i change this plugin direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery UI has it's own out of the box accordion which I think does what you want:

Have a look here:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/

Comment: thank you. i have to use 'fillSpace:true' with jQuery ui accordion plugin to get what i want.